# Fetch array element with highest prefix value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this. I want to retreive the array element with highest version number.

```
Array(
[0] => "ARRELEMENT_test",
[1] => "ARRELEMENT_test_v",
[2] => "ARRELEMENT_test_v5",
[3] => "ARRELEMENT_test_v1",
[4] => "ARRELEMENT_test_v2",
[5] => "ARRELEMENT_test_v3"
)
```

Here it should return `ARRELEMENT_test_v3` array element. Is there are any predefined function so that we can achieve this. I am trying like this.

```
function findPrefix($array) {
 $i = 1;

 while ($i < strlen($array[0])) {

  $match = substr($array[0], 0, $i);

  foreach ($array as $arr) {
  $nextmatch = substr($arr, 0, $i-1);
   if ($match < $nextmatch ) {
      //return array element with highest prefix
   }
  }
 $i++; // increase string length
 }
}
```

Comment: Using array sort then get the first item in array

Comment: Is your array actually this simple, or is this a cut-down example? Just running PHP's native `sort` function will work for this.

Comment: I may have some elements without version prefix also. I updated my question.

Comment: Why shouldn't it return `ARRELEMENT_test_v5` ? (I assume it was forget when editing)

Comment: Are all values with a fixed pattern like `X_Y` and optional `_Version` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getIndexOfMaxNumber($arr){
    //get the numeric value from the string and store it in an array
    foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
        preg_match('!\d+!', $val, $match);
        if($match){
            $index[$key]= $match[0];
        }
    }
    //Sort an array and maintain index association
    arsort($index); 
   //Set the internal pointer of an array to its first element
   reset($index);

   $first_key = key($index);
   return $first_key;
}
$maxIndex = getIndexOfMaxNumber($arr); 
echo $arr[$maxIndex];
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/OqIDH)